# Is there evidence to suggest Macsyma was directed at the Diophantine equations in the Entscheidungsproblem?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem, computer-algebra, algebra

I'm reading the book [The Annotated Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annotated_Turing) by [Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/). In it he mentions the [Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) - which was a joy to read.

This then lead to [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem) - finding an algorithm of solving Diophantine in a fixed number of steps to whole numbers. Interestingly enough - [Diophantine sets are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem#Applications) [Turing Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). (That last one kind of blows my mind).

Now this is what Turing was driving at in his [paper in 1936](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf). (On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem))

Now it seems to me that [Macsyma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macsyma) (with some [common heritage](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/06/there-was-a-time-before-mathematica/) to [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)) is directed at solving Computer Algebra problems.

Now the Entscheidungsproblem (or as we know it the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) has a relationship to Computer Algebra - but was more about the decidability rather than the symbolic mathematics. Can we say Macsyma was directed at both the symbolic mathematics and the halting problem?

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest Macsyma was directed at the Diophantine equations in the Entscheidungsproblem?**